# Get single parameter from joomla database

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, field

I'm trying to retrieve the image intro of an article outside the article component.
I'm using this query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('images')
 ->from('#__content')
 ->where('id = 151');
$db->setQuery($query);
$image = $db->loadResult();
echo $image;
```

The problem is the database field, where are stored many parameters, and the result of my query is this:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/myimage.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/myimage.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

How can i retrieve only the "image_intro" parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget to escape in your database query. I've made some changes to it for you:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('images'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote('151'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$image = $db->loadResult();
```

You then need to json_decode the result like so

```
$image_intro = json_decode($image);
$path = $image_intro->image_intro;
```

If you use `echo $path`, you will get the following output:

```
images/image_name.jpg
```

You can then display the image like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo JUri::root() . $path; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply get the `ContentModelArticle` and then load the specific article ID.

```
/* Lets say the article ID = 151 */
$id = 151;

/* Get an instance of the generic articles model
   @var ContentModelArticle $model */
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$myArticle = $model->getItem($id);

/* That way you have access to all the use params as well as the image you're after */
$images  = json_decode($myArticle->images);
$image_intro = $images->image_intro;
```

Article URLs can also be handled the same way…

```
$urls    = json_decode($myArticle->urls);
```

Or Article params…

```
$params  = $myArticle->params;
$page_heading = $params->get('page_heading');
```

Other useful params…

```
 $params->get('show_publish_date');
 $params->get('show_create_date');
 $params->get('show_hits');
 $params->get('show_category');
 $params->get('show_parent_category');
 $params->get('show_author');
```